# GeoExt Tree Example Modification

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

The example provided in http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/tree.html shows all overlayes are checked but how do I make these overlayes unchecked while page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a call to the (WMS) layer and specify the parameters & options, you can set the ***visibility*** to ***false*** -

```
    wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("wms", "http://os2k239.ordsvy.gov.uk/geoserver/wms?",
         {
                layers: "layer 1",
                format: 'image/png'
            },
            {singleTile: true, isBaseLayer: false, buffer: 0, **visibility: false**}
        );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

On

```
<input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" checked="">
```

Off

```
<input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox">
```

Recommend you use Firefox and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to view the source live when and can interactively select objects and change their state and see the source code change.

[image]